# How to get a post analytics from facebook api?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am letting users share videos on my site to their facebook timeline or pages. When they share the video I receive a post id back from the facebook api. 
How can I find out how likes that shared video received?

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: To collect the data about videos shared from my app.